# How to read and write tar file in C?

Tags: c, sockets, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I want to read the tar file and write it to another tar file using C. The procedure what I m following here is :

1. Creating a tar file of the folder
2. Writing client socket program for reading that tar file as binary file in C using fread function
3. Writing whatever comes in buffer to socket
4. Writing server socket program to receive sent data into a buffer
5. Writing the received buffer into the another tar file.
6. Closing files and socket.

Here is code :

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define MAX 1024
#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/foo"

int s, s2, t, len;
struct sockaddr_un local, remote;

void createSSocket()
{
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nServer Socket Created...");
}

void setSSocketPath()
{
    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    printf("\nServer Socket Path Set...");
}

void bindSocket()
{
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) 
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSocket Binded...");
}

void listenSocket()
{   
    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) 
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nListening Socket...");
}

void acceptConnection()
{
    printf("\nWaiting for a connection...");
    t = sizeof(remote);
    if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nServer Socket Connected...");
}

void closeSSocket()
{
    close(s);
    close(s2);
    printf("\nServer Socket Closed...");
}


void receiveTar()
{
    int len,ret;
    char buf[MAX] = {0};
    char path[MAX] = "/home/priyanka/Codes/3455.tgz";
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(path,"wb");

    while((len = recv(s2,buf,MAX,0)) > 0)
    {
        buf[len] = 0;
        printf("\nReceived : %d",len);
        //fputs(buf,fp);
        //printf("%s",buf);
        ret = fwrite(buf,1,strlen(buf),fp);
        if(ret == -1)
        {
            perror("Error writing to file");
        }
        printf("    Write : %d",ret);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    createSSocket();    
    setSSocketPath();
    bindSocket();
    listenSocket();
    acceptConnection(); 

    receiveTar();

    closeSSocket();
    return 0;   
}
```

Output of Server Program :

Server Socket Created... 
Server Socket Path Set...
Socket Binded...
Listening Socket...
Waiting for a connection...
Server Socket Connected...
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 459  Write : 459
Received : 239  Write : 239
Received : 529  Write : 529
Received : 425  Write : 425
Received : 411  Write : 411
Received : 493  Write : 493
Received : 142  Write : 142
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 397  Write : 397
Received : 41   Write : 41
Received : 158  Write : 158
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 705  Write : 705
Received : 505  Write : 505
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 87   Write : 87
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 326  Write : 326
Received : 234  Write : 234
Received : 311  Write : 311
Received : 819  Write : 819
Received : 571  Write : 571
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 1024 Write : 1024
Received : 341  Write : 341
Received : 243  Write : 243
Received : 630  Write : 630
Received : 50   Write : 50
Received : 35   Write : 35
Received : 215  Write : 215
Server Socket Closed...

Client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define MAX 1024
#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/foo"


int s, t, len;
struct sockaddr_un remote;

void createCSocket()
{
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nClient Socket Created...");
}

void setCSocketPath()
{
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    printf("\nClient Socket Path Set...");
}

void connectSocket()
{
    printf("\nTrying to connect...");
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) 
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nClient Connected...\n");
}

void closeCSocket()
{
    close(s);
    printf("\nClient Socket Closed...");
}

void sendTar()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ret,len;
    char buf[MAX] = {0};
    fp = fopen("/home/priyanka/3455.tgz","rb");
    while(len = fread(buf,1,1024,fp))
    //while((buf[0] = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("\nRead : %d",len);
        ret = send(s,buf,strlen(buf),0);
        printf("    Sent : %d",ret);
        if(ret == -1)
        {
            perror("Error sending data : Client");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    createCSocket();
    setCSocketPath();
    connectSocket();

    sendTar();

    closeCSocket(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output of Client Program :

Client Socket Created...
Client Socket Path Set...
Trying to connect...
Client Connected...

Read : 1024 Sent : 3
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 273
Read : 1024 Sent : 180
Read : 1024 Sent : 239
Read : 1024 Sent : 529
Read : 1024 Sent : 425
Read : 1024 Sent : 411
Read : 1024 Sent : 493
Read : 1024 Sent : 142
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 394
Read : 1024 Sent : 41
Read : 1024 Sent : 158
Read : 1024 Sent : 702
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 503
Read : 1024 Sent : 2
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 84
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 323
Read : 1024 Sent : 234
Read : 1024 Sent : 311
Read : 1024 Sent : 819
Read : 1024 Sent : 571
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 1027
Read : 1024 Sent : 335
Read : 1024 Sent : 243
Read : 1024 Sent : 630
Read : 1024 Sent : 50
Read : 1024 Sent : 35
Read : 315  Sent : 215
Client Socket Closed...

I m facing problems like :

1. Whatever I m reading in client program only few bytes of it are actually sent and still the receive function is reading MAX number of bytes. Whereas I want my program to read 1024 bytes, sent 1024 bytes, receive 1024 bytes and write 1024 bytes, which is not happening in this case. Will sending length of buffer help to sort out the problem??
2. Is it the way I m using the right one to send tar file over socket or are there different ways of doing it??
3. How to check if the data is successfully read, sent, received and written??

Comment: `while(len = fread(buf,1,1024,fp))` is *very* bad style.  You should use `while((len = fread(buf,1,1024,fp)) > 0)` instead, and enable more compiler warnings: `-Wall` for gcc and clang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading a binary file with `fread` and sending chunks as if they were strings:

```
        ret = send(s,buf,strlen(buf),0);
```

Use this instead to send just `len` bytes.

```
        ret = send(s,buf,len,0);
```

Similarly, the server program should just write the `len` bytes received.  Appending a `'\0'` may cause a buffer overflow and writing `strlen(buf)` bytes will fail to write all the bytes received if a NUL byte is received, as will certainly be the case if a tar file is transmitted:

Change the logic to:

```
    ret = fwrite(buf,1,len,fp);
```

You may also want to use the netcat utility: `man nc`

Answer (score 2):

There are several versions of [libtar](http://destructor.de/libtar/index.htm), a library to read and write `tar` archive files in C. You should use it.

If using a network thru [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) [sockets(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) (e.g. on Linux or POSIX), remember that [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) is just a *stream* of bytes *without* any notion of message: a [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) (or `write`) operation on the emitting side does not necessarily correspond to a single [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) (or `read`) operation on the recieving side, the "packets" might have been fragmented or reassembled (e.g. by intermediate routers or by your network hardware or controller or kernel layer). So you always should buffer and manage the byte count of partial `read`,`send`,`write`,`recv` operations.

Comment: The OP's assignment does not go this far ;-)