# Copying a directory using sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a program in C that sends files across the network using sockets. This works fine for files - they are read into a buffer and then written onto the socket. They are picked up at the other end by reversing this process.

However, how can this apply to directories? I also want to copy directories, keeping the permissions the same (so I don't think mkdir will work). At the moment when I try to run this on a directory, it says the size is -1. How is a directory represented?

To be clear, for example, if I want my program to copy /tmp across the network, it will do this:

```
/tmp/1.txt - OK
/tmp/2.txt - OK
/tmp/dir/  - Skip
/tmp/dir/3.txt - Can't write to path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is homework, otherwise why not use FTP, `scp`, `rsync`, `unison`  etc.

To test if a file path is a plain file, a device, a directory, etc etc... use
[stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)

To read a directory, use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) then loop on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (then of course `closedir`). You don't need to know how a directory is represented.

You probably should be interested in [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) to recursively traverse a file tree.

To make one directory, use [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

BTW, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092240/841108) contains useful information too...

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.  It would fit fairly will with what you have already to `tar` the directory to transfer, send the resulting archive across the network, and un`tar` on the other side.

Alternatively, you can walk the directory tree recursively.  For each directory you need transfer only the name and whichever attributes you want to preserve, but then you must list the directory contents (probably via `readdir()`) and transfer each member.

By the way, don't neglect to think about how you're going to handle links, both symbolic ones and hard ones.  And if you want your program to be really robust then consider also what to do with special files such as device files and FIFOs.